# When adding to array, and trying to display the contents after a make a new instance it will not display - ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays

I am very new to Ruby and I am trying to do an exercise on a book.

I have 3 classes, one is the menu that interacts with the user, the other one creates objects books, and the other one stores the books into array, the problem I am having is when I add a book and then ask the user if he wants to continue to the menu, then I ran `Menu.new` and it returns the user to the menu, when I select option 3 to show the arrays content, in this case the books I've stored, its not showing anything. What am i doing wrong?

**book**

```
class Book 
    attr_accessor :name
    def initialize(name, author)
        @name = name
        @author = author
    end

    def to_s
        "Book: #{@name} Autor: #{@author}"
    end
end
```

**bookshelf**

```
class Bookshelf 
    def initialize
        @array = []
    end

    def +(arg)
        @array << arg
    end

    def -(arg)
        @array.delete(arg)
    end

    def showAll
        puts @array
    end

    def search(book)
        @array.each do |x| if x == book
            puts "book is here!"
        else
            puts "book is not here! "
        end
    end
end
```

**menu**

```
class Menu
    def initialize 
        menu
    end

    def menu    
        puts "Menu

        1. Add book
        2. Delete book
        3. Show All
        4. Search book
        5. Exit"

        bookshelf = Bookshelf.new
        answ = gets.chomp.to_i
        case answ   
        when 1
        answ = "yes"
        while answ == "yes"

            puts "Book:"
            name_book = gets
            puts "Author:"
            name_author = gets

            name_book = Book.new(name_book, name_author)
            name_book = name_book.name
            bookshelf+ name_book

            puts "Add another book?"
            answ= gets.chomp
            end 
            puts "Return to menu?"
            answer2 = gets.chomp

            if answer2 == "yes"
                bookshelf.showAll
                Menu.new
            else
                puts "bye!"
                bookshelf.showAll
            end    
        when 2
            puts "Book:"
            book_delete = gets
            bookshelf- book_delete
            bookshelf.showAll
            puts "Youve deleted: #{book_delete}"
            puts "Return to menu?"
            answer = gets.chomp
            if answer == "yes"
                Menu.new
            else
                puts "bye!"
            end             
        when 3
            puts "Here are all the books stored:"
            bookshelf.showAll
            puts "Return to menu?"
            answer = gets
            if answer == "yes"
                Menu.new
            else
                puts "bye!"
            end
        end 
    end
    Menu.new
end
```

Comment: Put your classed in the post..not in the comment. In your post section.. a lot of spaces are left for you.

Comment: Done, i think, hehe, sorry my first post on stackoverflow

Comment: No worries, @danielbenson. Everyone has a first post SO. What matters is you are willing to learn what makes a great post. You appear to be one who is willing!

Comment: Yeah, i am, ive been learning ruby by myself for the past 2 months and its great!, only that ive encounter this big wall, this lesson excersice i cannot finish.

Comment: This is unrelated to your problem but your `gets` in your third case statement option needs a `.chomp` at the end.

Comment: thanks, @CharlesCaldwell i will include it

Answer (score 0):

You should set the array member of bookshelf as global. That would solve your problem.

A better aproach is to set the Menu's member bookshelf (yes, the object) as a member of Menu, but if you use Menu.new you are creating a new instance and so destroying that bookshelf member. So here you have two options:

- Do not destroy that menu nor initialize a new one when you whant the user to return to the menu and use the same menu all the time (singleton). What I would do.
- set that bookshelf member also as global.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple issues with your code. I'll cover them one at a time.

Your immediate issue is you are calling `Menu.new` from inside your `while` loop. This means you are getting a completely new menu, with a brand new bookshelf, each time the user wants to return to the menu and keys in "yes". You should probably just repeat the menu over and over (hence the `while` loop) instead of asking the user each time if they want to return to the menu since your menu has an exit option (though you haven't coded it yet).

Here's a quick example:

```
# ... display menu
# Let's say choice 5 is 'Exit'
choice = gets.chomp
until choice == "5" 

# case statement that does something for options 1 - 4

end

# Then end the method which means once use picks "5", the menu closes
```

The main issue is you are calling `Menu.new` at the end of your `Menu` class definition. Remember that your definition of a class is just a blueprint for an actual instance of a class. When you make a blueprint for a house, the blueprint doesn't build the house. The builder builds the house.

Your code really should read something like:

```
class Menu
    # code
end

myMenu = Menu.new
```

You can call the method `menu` from your `initialize` method but it is better Ruby practice to call it outside the method. Let the builder decide if he wants to build the wall or the floor first. So:

```
myMenu = Menu.new
myMenu.menu
```

This should help you sort out a few of your issues and help you get going in your further learning. I've tried to shorten this as much as possible since it has the opprotunity of being a very broad disscussion.

Comment: Thanks so much Charles! that fixed it! i arranged the untill at the beginning of my Menu class and that did the trick! also i will follow your advice about the best practice, will erase the initialize from my Menu class and just define the menu class and load the menu with the .menu method, thanks!